# Notation for a vector of integers with no duplicates

Tags: notation, vectors

Consider for example the notation $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{Z}^4$. This could mean that $\mathbf{x}$ contains duplicate values, e.g. $\mathbf{x}=\{0,0,1,2\}$. Is there any way I can express that $\mathbf{x}$ is a vector of integers *without* any duplicates, e.g. $\mathbf{x}=\{5,4,3,2\}$? Or should I just mention it in the text?

Comment: Maybe you can say, each component of 4-tuple is distinct.

Comment: As far as I know, this property is rarely met, so I don't think it deserves a special treatment. Just mention it.

Comment: It’s worth noting that $\mathbb{Z}^4$ is not actually a vector space; however, it is a [module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_(mathematics)).

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is:

$$ \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{Z}^4\ \mathrm{such\ that}\ \forall(i,j\ \mathrm{such\ that}\ i\neq j)\ x_i\neq x_j$$

Comment: $$ \mathbf x\in\left\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\in\mathbb Z^4 \mid \forall i,j\in\{1,2,3,4\}\:(i\ne j{\implies} x_i\ne x_j)\right\}$$

Answer (score 0):

Just mention it in the text.

If you need this structure often, invent and explain notation - something like

> We will use boldface lower case letters and angle brackets for vectors
> (lists, sequences) of distinct integers as in $$ \mathbf{x} = \langle 3, 1, -2, 4 \rangle. $$